# Programmatically creating a task in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a simple scenario:  I am reading an article on the Internet Explorer of my Windows Phone 8.  I want to file away the link to this article in the Tasks list of my Exchange account (which is already added to the phone).

Today, I cannot do this so I thought I will build a small app that will act as a "share target" when the user shares the URL from Internet Explorer.  The app will receive the URL and then programmatically create an Outlook task.  I am not sure if that second part is possible.  Has anyone tried something like this?

Comment: I dound this thing about EWS Managed API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).  Not sure whether this API can be used from Phone